# Transpose single column in dax or power query

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have a required where i need to transpose specific column using Powerbi calculated column /power query

```
1 Dressing
1 Transferring
2 Bathing
2 Dressing
3 Transferring

**Is there anyway to transpose it to the following:**

1 Bathing Dressing Transferring
2 Bathing Dressing
3 Transferring
```

Comment: Pivot/UnPivot in the power query editor

Comment: Hi Jon, Actually i need to pivot only one column, so i think we can't pivot/unpivot only one column.

Comment: 1 has no Transferring in the input data. Is that a mistake in the sample putput?

Comment: Hi @R_R, Thanks for your answer, id 1 has transferring as well. But i can use the given power query for transformation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If **Transferring** is there for ID 1 is a mistake, you can perform some transformation in **Power Query Editor** to achieve the required output.

Let, your table looks as below-

[image]

Now follow this below steps-

Step-1:
Apply a **GROUP BY** on ID column as shown below-

[image]

Step-2:
Create a custom column as below-

[image]

Step-3:
Now extract the values from the new **Custom** column as below-

[image]

**Here** is the final output. You can remove column **grouped_data** at the end.

[image]